# Xcode Cannot assign push to a button in view

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, view, push

I am using xCode 4.2. I have most of the interface in the mainstoryboard.xib. However a listing detail is using its own xib. It is a tabbed and navigation based project. On every view when a ctrl click a button "Push" option is available however on this detail view.xib its not. And hence I cannot make the button clcikable and make it open another view. I only see Did End on Exit, touch Down, etc. when I ctrl Clcik the button.

Anyone know why this happens? is this because it is not in the mainstoryboard? is it possible to make it clickable programmatically?

Comment: Where is the view controller that you want to push?  Is it in the storyboard, or in another nib, or do you create it programmatically?

Comment: its in another nib. Not programmatically.

Comment: Its a view controller with map view. What I want to do is to bring it up with the push of a button. and while doing that I want to send two variables to it; the latitude, and the longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't include it in the storyboard for some reason then you will have to load and push it in code. This is pretty standard code - create a new instance of the view controller using `initWithNibName:`, pass it any detail variables,  then tell your navigation controller to push the new controller. This code will have to be linked to an action in the view controller that holds the button.